# Routing parameters in a custom mvc

Tags: php, function, class, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to route like domain.com/users/username, I can get all users list like domain.com/users but when I try to go for domain.com/users/username and than I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error 404 page not found

My routes.php is like following :

```
$router->get('users', 'UsersController@index');
$router->get('users/{username}', 'UsersController@show');
```

UserController is :

```
class UsersController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = App::get('database')->selectAll('users');

        return view('users', compact('users'));
    }
    
    public function show($username)
    {
        $user = App::get('database')->select('users', ['name' => $username]);

        return view('user', compact('user'));
    }

}
```

Show.view.php is created in partials directory:

```
<?php require 'partials/head.php' ?>

<h1>Users Name</h1>

<?php foreach ($filterUsers as $user): ?>
    <p><?php echo $user['name']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>


<?php require 'partials/footer.php';
```

My Router class is like following :

```
class Router
{
    protected $routes = [
        'GET' => [],
        'POST' => [],
    ];

    public static function load($file)
    {
        $router = new static();

        require $file;

        return $router;
    }

    public function get($url, $controller)
    {
        $this->routes['GET'][$url] = $controller;
    }

    public function post($url, $controller)
    {
        $this->routes['POST'][$url] = $controller;
    }

    public function direct($uri, $requestType)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes[$requestType])) {
            return $this->callAction(
                ...explode('@', $this->routes[$requestType][$uri])
            );
        }

        throw new Exception('Error 404 page not found');
    }

    protected function callAction($controller, $action)
    {
        $controller = "App\\Controllers\\{$controller}";
        $controller = new $controller();
        if (method_exists($controller, $action)) {
            return $controller->$action();
        }

        throw new Exception('Error method not found');
    }
}
```

Request class is set correctly :

```
class Request
{
    public static function uri()
    {
        return trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
    }

    public static function method()
    {
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }
}
```

Bootstrap.php :

```
use App\Core\App;
use App\Core\Database\Connection;
use App\Core\Database\QueryBuilder;

App::bind('config', require 'config.php');
App::bind('database', new QueryBuilder(
    Connection::make(App::get('config')['database'])
));

function view($viewName, $data = [])
{
    extract($data);

    return require "app/views/{$viewName}.view.php";
}

function redirect($path)
{
    header("location: /{$path}");
    exit();
}

function dd($var)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    die(var_dump($var));
}
```

Comment: I’m not seeing how you are accounting for templates/placeholders such as `{username}`, you appear to just be doing a simple array key lookup

Comment: @ChrisHaas I just started it and not complete yet, I am trying to do it simple way with bootstraping I added bootstrap into the question.

Comment: I’m just trying to understand `if(array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes[$requestType])){}`. If the array holds `/user/{username}`, and you visit `/user/chris`, there won’t be a match. You’ll need to build a pattern matcher into the system

Comment: You mean build patern in class Router ? I am not very familier to mvc sorry.

Comment: I can’t tell you what specifically to build, but your code is basically doing this right now: https://3v4l.org/ZYb5r. The strings will never compare unless the person’s name is literally `{username}`. You _could_ do what you are doing as a “fast first pass”, and then add in a [more complicated thing](https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router/blob/cd891d53349e878e1b577d720ae28d570110eb47/src/Pecee/SimpleRouter/Route/Route.php#L120) before treating it as a 404